# Prisma returns empty response when fetching data

Tags: mysql, prisma, planetscale

I have data in the table but prisma returns empty response.
Database is hosted on Planetscale and it is MySQL.
This is schema of the table:

```
model BindingTeacherLessons {
  bindingId Int
  teacherId Int
  lessons   Int

  binding Binding @relation(fields: [bindingId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  teacher Teacher @relation(fields: [teacherId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)

  @@id([bindingId, teacherId])
  @@index([bindingId])
  @@index([teacherId])
}
```

This query returns {} and no errors

```
const response = prisma.bindingTeacherLessons.findMany({})
```

Comment: I believe this is resolved now! :) It would be helpful to someone else if you can post the solution that worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem was that I have populated BindingTeacherLessons table with createMany(). Fix was to populate it with create().

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).